# How to to insert two records for the new entry into the same column using triggers

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE TABLE source_det 
(
    det_id number(10) by default IDENTITY
    e_id       NUMBER(10),
    sys_name   VARCHAR2(20),
    ref_id     NUMBER(10),
    sys_other  VARCHAR2(30)
);

INSERT INTO source_det VALUES(1,11,'SOURCE',992,null);
INSERT INTO source_det VALUES(2,11,'SOURCE',637,null);
```

Audit table:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE audit_tab_sq;

CREATE TABLE audit_tab 
(
    a_id       NUMBER(10) default audit_tab_sq.nextval,
    l_transaction varchar2(20),--INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
    e_id       NUMBER(10),
    sys_name   VARCHAR2(20),
    value_old  VARCHAR2(20),
    value_new  VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

My attempt:

```
create or replace trigger audit_tab_trg
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON source_det 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
--INSERTING
if :new.ref_id is not null  THEN
  INSERT INTO audit_tab (a_id,l_transaction,e_id, sys_name,value_old,value_new)
     VALUES (audit_tab_sq.NEXTVAL,'INSERT',:new.e_id,:new.sys_name,NULL,:new.ref_id);
elsif :new.sys_other is not null then
  INSERT INTO audit_tab (a_id,l_transaction,e_id, sys_name,value_old,value_new)
     VALUES (audit_tab_sq.NEXTVAL,'INSERT',:new.e_id,:new.sys_name,NULL,:new.sys_other);
elsif (:new.ref_id is not null) AND (:new.sys_other is not null) then
  INSERT INTO audit_tab (a_id,l_transaction,e_id, sys_name,value_old,value_new)
     VALUES (audit_tab_sq.NEXTVAL,'INSERT',:new.e_id,:new.sys_name,NULL,:new.ref_id); 
  INSERT INTO audit_tab (a_id,l_transaction,e_id, sys_name,value_old,value_new)
     VALUES (audit_tab_sq.NEXTVAL,'INSERT',:new.e_id,:new.sys_name,NULL,:new.sys_other); 
end if;

end;
```

Problem statement:

1. I need to insert a record into the audit table whenever new insertion or updating happens.

Trigger is working fine when I am giving single value for either `ref_id` or `sys_other` but not working when giving both the column values at once as explained below

```
INSERT INTO source_det VALUES (13, 'TARGET', 637, null);
```

Getting inserted into the audit table:

```
+------+---------------+------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| a_id | l_transaction | e_id | sys_name | value_old | value_new |
+------+---------------+------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|    1 | INSERT        |  13  | TARGET   | null      |       637 |
+------+---------------+------+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

But when I am inserting both the records i.e for `ref_id` and `sys_other` then two entries should be inserted into the audit table

```
INSERT INTO source_det VALUES (15, 'SOURCE', 637, 'Upload');
```

Current Output:

```
+------+---------------+------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| a_id | l_transaction | e_id | sys_name | value_old | value_new |
+------+---------------+------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|    1 | INSERT        |  15  | SOURCE   | null      |       637 |
+------+---------------+------+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Expected Output:

```
+------+---------------+------+----------+-----------+-----------+--+
| a_id | l_transaction | e_id | sys_name | value_old | value_new |  |
+------+---------------+------+----------+-----------+-----------+--+
|    1 | INSERT        |  15  | SOURCE   | null      | 637       |  |
|    2 | INSERT        |   15 | SOURCE   | null      | Upload    |  |
+------+---------------+------+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Same for update how to do this:

Below is the try which I have given

```
if (:old.ref_id != :new.ref_id ) then
  INSERT INTO audit_tab (a_id,l_transaction,e_id, sys_name,value_old,value_new)
     VALUES (audit_tab_sq.NEXTVAL,'UPDATE',:old.e_id,:old.sys_name,:old.ref_id,:new.ref_id);
elsif (:old.sys_other != :new.sys_other ) then
  INSERT INTO audit_tab (a_id,l_transaction,e_id, sys_name,value_old,value_new)
     VALUES (audit_tab_sq.NEXTVAL,'UPDATE',:old.e_id,:old.sys_name,:old.sys_other,:new.sys_other);
end if;
```

Tool used: SQL Developer(18c)

Comment: Also asked at https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4496445/how-to-to-insert-two-records-for-the-new-entry-into-the-same-column-using-triggers#latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IFs should be rearranged  so that the "last" (in your code) is examined "first":

```
SQL> create or replace trigger audit_tab_trg
  2    after insert or delete or update on source_det
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5  if (:new.ref_id is not null) and (:new.sys_other is not null) then
  6    insert into audit_tab (a_id,l_transaction,e_id, sys_name,value_old,value_new)
  7       values (audit_tab_sq.nextval,'INSERT',:new.e_id,:new.sys_name,null,:new.ref_id);
  8    insert into audit_tab (a_id,l_transaction,e_id, sys_name,value_old,value_new)
  9       values (audit_tab_sq.nextval,'INSERT',:new.e_id,:new.sys_name,null,:new.sys_other);
 10  elsif :new.ref_id is not null  then
 11    insert into audit_tab (a_id,l_transaction,e_id, sys_name,value_old,value_new)
 12       values (audit_tab_sq.nextval,'INSERT',:new.e_id,:new.sys_name,null,:new.ref_id);
 13  elsif :new.sys_other is not null then
 14    insert into audit_tab (a_id,l_transaction,e_id, sys_name,value_old,value_new)
 15       values (audit_tab_sq.nextval,'INSERT',:new.e_id,:new.sys_name,null,:new.sys_other);
 16  end if;
 17  end;
 18  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into source_det (det_id, e_id, sys_name, ref_id, sys_other)
  2  values (audit_tab_sq.nextval, 15, 'SOURCE', 637, 'Upload');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from audit_tab;

      A_ID L_TRANSACTION              E_ID SYS_NAME             VALUE_OLD            VALUE_NEW
---------- -------------------- ---------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
        10 INSERT                       15 SOURCE                                    637
        11 INSERT                       15 SOURCE                                    Upload

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for this my IFs was not rearranged. Good catch and I tried for UPDATE but this is inserting new record
```
if (:old.ref_id != :new.ref_id ) then
  INSERT INTO audit_tab (a_id,l_transaction,e_id, sys_name,value_old,value_new)
     VALUES (audit_tab_sq.NEXTVAL,'UPDATE',:old.e_id,:old.sys_name,:old.ref_id,:new.ref_id);
elsif (:old.sys_other != :new.sys_other ) then
  INSERT INTO audit_tab (a_id,l_transaction,e_id, sys_name,value_old,value_new)
     VALUES (audit_tab_sq.NEXTVAL,'UPDATE',:old.e_id,:old.sys_name,:old.sys_other,:new.sys_other);
end if;
```

Comment: This is difficult to read. I suggest you edit the original message (question) you posted and present your last code.

Comment: I have edited the original question and added the logic which is not working for UPDATE

Comment: Looks like you should "split" code into several cases, i.e. `IF INSERTING THEN ` should use code you initially posted (rearranged, though); then, `ELSIF UPDATING THEN ` should take care about what happens when you update existing rows (pay attention to possible NULL values! They aren't equal (or different) from anything else, so you should either use NVL function or add e.g. `or :old.ref_id is null`. What's left then is `ELSIF DELETING THEN `.

Comment: I did not get this part pay attention to possible NULL values! They aren't equal (or different) from anything else, so you should either use NVL function or add e.g. or :old.ref_id is null

Comment: For example, if old value is NULL and you update it to 123, then - if you check it as `if :old.value <> :new.value`, it is kind of "obvious" that they are different, but - as far as Oracle is concerned, this evaluates to FALSE because you should've checked it as e.g. `if nvl(:old.value, -1) <> nvl(:new.value, -1) then ...`

Comment: Thats worked for me and one last question can we use JOINS while inserting into the audit table? Because wherever id column value is there I need to fetch the id value from lookup table and same should be stored in the audit table

Comment: Yes, no problem, you can use joins. Just pay attention NOT to select from the same table trigger is based on because you'll get the *mutating table* error. It can be fixed (with e.g. compound trigger), but - usually it just means *bad practice*. If you'd like to select from a different - lookup - table, as I said - no problem.

Comment: ok Then probably I have to do 
```INSERT INTO SELECT ( :new.value or :old.value) JOIN lookup table``` like this ?

Comment: Something like `insert into audit_tab (...) select ... from lookup_table a where a.id = :new.id and ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
Testing : we can  reduce the code for code redundancy. find below updated code.

    create or replace trigger audit_tab_trg
      after insert or delete or update on source_det
       for each row
       begin
       if :new.ref_id is not null  then
        insert into audit_tab (a_id,l_transaction,e_id, sys_name,value_old,value_new)
           values (audit_tab_sq.nextval,'INSERT',:new.e_id,:new.sys_name,null,:new.ref_id);
      end if;       
      if :new.sys_other is not null then
        insert into audit_tab (a_id,l_transaction,e_id, sys_name,value_old,value_new)
           values (audit_tab_sq.nextval,'INSERT',:new.e_id,:new.sys_name,null,:new.sys_other);
      end if;
     end;
```

Comment: Thanks for this but this won't work if we give values for two columns at once which I had explained in my original question